# pppd default route configuration

Tags: route

I'm running pppd in a Ubuntu VM. When it's connected the ip route is like this

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.154.2 dev eth0 onlink
XX.XX.250.5 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src XX.XX.250.43
172.16.177.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.177.200
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.154.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.154.200
```

The eth0 is the default route out

```
# ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.154.2 dev eth0  src 192.168.154.200
    cache
```

Now, I need to route everything through ppp0 (except for the remote PPP server), any ideas?

P.S I've tried the following and it just cut all internet connections,

```
route add default gw XX.XX.250.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved.

Simply instruct sstpc to save server route by adding the `--save-server-route` parameter and let pppd replace the default route by enabling the `replacedefaultroute` option.